# Strange behaviour of two successive printf() calls in C

Tags: c, printf

*I was playing with C; check this out:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    printf("%d\n", 1.5);
    printf("%f", 0);
}
```

*I expected the output:*

```
0
0.000000
```

*but it prints:*

```
0
1.500000
```

Did the first `printf()` pass the `1.5` to second `printf()`?

PS: I'm aware of ( `%d` for ints, `%f` for floats ). As I mentioned, I was just messing with the code.

PS2: I'm using DevC++ & Code::Blocks.

Comment: `void main()` illegal signature! --> `int main(void)`. The rest invokes undefined behaviour, too. Read the man-page and a good C book, This is absolute basic stuff.

Comment: You're not using any function (or any identifier) declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Including it is redundant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The behavior is undefined as per the C Standard, here is what may be happening on your system:

- For the first call `printf("%d\n", 1.5);` `main` passes the floating point value `1.5` as a double in the first XMM register and call `printf()`.
- `printf()` does not modify the XMM register because if does not perform any floating point operation to handle the format `"%d"`. It retrieves the value to print from a different place: a register or the stack, and this value happens to be `0`.
- for the second call `printf("%f", 0);`, `main` does not change the XMM either because it passes an `int` value of `0` via the other place, a register or the stack.
- the second `printf()` finally gets the `double` value for the format `%f` from the XMM register where `1.5` has been stored earlier. Hence the output `1.500000`.

None of the above is guaranteed in any way, but this is probably the explanation you are interested in. Different systems may handle parameter passing in different ways, they are part of the ABI (Application Binary Interface).

Just for fun, you might want to try this variation:

```
printf("first %d, second %f\n", 1.5, 42);
```

which on my system outputs `first 42, second 1.500000`

Comment: Are you sure XMM is used in all cases (both 32 and 64 bits systems)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: no, I'm not sure, hence *what may be happening on your system*... It seems to be the case in 64-bit systems, probably not on 32-bit systems.  I cannot test for the Windows system the OP uses.

Comment: Good intuition for a 64 bits compilation (a really messy ABI). On a 32 bits system this could happen too using advanced optimizations that are supposed to use XMM too for performance reasons. Anyway I hope the user got  tons of warnings, or the compiler is really poor.

Answer (score 7):

You've got some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (so *arbitrarily bad* things could [happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) and you should not expect anything good). With `%f` the [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function expects a `double` (notice that when passed as argument a `float` gets promoted to a `double`) but `0` is a literal of type `int`. Also, different compilers (even different *versions* of the same compiler) or different *optimization flags* could produce different bad effects.

Please read Lattner's blog on [*What Every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

<sup>(a good attitude towards undefined behavior is to try hard to always avoid it; don't lose your time in trying to understand what concretely happens; but consider UB as something very *dirty* or "*sick*" that you always avoid)</sup>

To explain the observed behavior, you need to dive into the specifics of your particular implementation, notably the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (for variadic functions à la `printf`). Also, look into the generated assembler code (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O1`); it might be possible that a double argument is passed in a register (or some [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) slot) different than an `int` argument (so the `printf` function is getting the garbage happening to sit in that location or register); notice also that quite often `sizeof(int)` could be 4 but `sizeof(double)` could be 8 (so the amount of data is not even right).

To avoid such mistakes, take the habit of compiling with a good compiler (such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) in the [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) realm) and enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). The compiler would have warned you.

BTW, `void main()` is illegal. It should be at least `int main(void)` and preferably `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and you should take care of the arguments.

With your example, `gcc -Wall -Wextra` (using GCC 7) tells (for your source file `april.c`):

```
april.c:4:10: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
     void main() {
          ^~~~
april.c: In function ‘main’:
april.c:5:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’,
                       but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n", 1.5);
             ~^
             %f
april.c:6:14: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, 
                       but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%f", 0);
             ~^
             %d
```

NB: [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) and [CodeBlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) are *not* compilers, but [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s. They both run some *external* [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) on your system).

Comment: OP apparently is well aware he does something invalid. So it boild down to "if I don't follow language rules, why does the language not do what I want?" And an empty argument list is an obsolescent feature for a definition (it is wrong for a declaration already). So it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Olaf That was my point, all I wanted is to check the output while not following the rules.
"Difficult Roads Often Lead To Beautiful Destinations"
 I tried to discover some new mind-blowing ways to do this kind of stuff, & apparently it lead to an undefined behavior but got the exactly to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AprilJohnson: The word **undefined** was choosen intentionally. There is no "expectable" result. A different compiler/(version/options, different time of day, different climate, different environment, etc. can yield a different result, including formatting your hard drive or nasal daemons.